# How do you do this (jQuery code) in MooTools?

Tags: mootools

jQuery code:

```
$.get('/', function(d) { alert($(d).find('a').length); });
```

Specifically running a selector on the returned content of an XMLHttpRequest...

MooTools code:

```
var opt = { url : '/', onComplete : function(d) { alert(d); } };
new Request(opt).send();
```

What do I do with `d` inside of onComplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use Request.HTML though (so it actually returns the html tree that a selector can crawl through)

```
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/',
    method: 'get',
    onComplete: function() {
        // normalise the collection so we can apply methods to it. 
        console.log($$(this.response.tree).getElement("a.foo")); // or getElements()
    }
}).send();
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/NF2jz/477/

`onComplete: function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript)` so first named arg is your response tree (if you are keeping `this` bound to something else)

in any case, you can always do: (within the onComplete) `console.log(this.response)` and inspect what arrives. if no element collection (normal request) then you can inject this.response.text into a new element and then run the selector on it.